# Is my own application on macOS allowed to delete it's cache from Library?

Tags: macos

I couldn't find a clear answer on the web and I don't know if there is any guideline from Apple that would disallow such functionally.

I'd like to know if my own application is allowed to clear it's own cache from the Library folder for both scenarios (AppStore vs. downloaded from the Web)?

Comment: If it's downloaded from the web, there aren't really any restrictions on what it can do. Can you be more specific about what you're wanting to delete, though? Is this a cache that your app creates?

Comment: @tubedogg In the original post I'm saying it's my own app to be more general. I cleaned up my system and found almost 2gb of caches from Spotify (even if I don't use it for offline streaming on my mac). The support told me the way they deal with that is to delete it manually (non experienced user won't even know of caches). In general as a developer I'd like to know if my app will create similar caches and if I'll ship it on the AppStore, if I'm allowed to clear this mess or will it be rejected from the AppStore.

Comment: Deleting files that your own app creates is not against any MAS rules that I'm aware of. If it was, computers would be littered with cache files that are never removed. It sounds like Spotify simply hasn't implemented a "clear cache" button.